# MainActivity is not an enclosing class, "this" makes a constructor error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to android studio and i have a problem when I'm trying to jump to a new activity, so when the line is:

```
public class signup_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton logupButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_activity);

    logupButton = findViewById(R.id.signuparrow);

    logupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, signup_activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}}
```

I get the error:

> 'com.example.myapplication.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class

and i so a couple of of people advising to chane the intent to this instead of MainActivity.this
but when im changing to this i get the error:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'intent'

Comment: "I get the error: 'com.example.myapplication.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class" -- your activity class is named `signup_activity`, not `MainActivity`. You also seem to be creating an `Intent` that will start the activity that you are in: this code is in `signup_activity` and you are going to start `signup_activity`.

Answer (score 1):

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, signup_activity.class);
```

Several things:

- First, the first param of `Intent()` constructor is a context. Since you are on `signup_activity` you need to do `signup_activity.this` to use it as a context.
- I'd assume you want to go to MainActivity, so your second param should be MainActivity.class. It seems you got the order altered there.

Answer (score 1):

you are in signup_activity and when use Intent in fisrt part you should call the current contex to jump to other activity.
so you should replace

**Intent intent = new Intent(signup_activity.this, MainActivity.class);**

if you want to jump to signup_activity you can call intent from MainActivity.